# Can a String variable, lets say 'String str', be directly copied into array?

Tags: c++

If I have a string and I want to reverse it without using built in function. Is it possible to copy string into array directly?

```
Void Main ()
{
    string str = "Abc";
    int length = strlen(str);
    char strArray[len]; 
    str = strArray
    String str2 = new String()
    for (int i=length-1, i>=0, i--)
         { 
             str2 = str2 +strArray[i];
         }
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using (that provides `String` and `Char`)?

Comment: ...and lets you leave out the semicolons?

Comment: you don't need a C array when std::string can act as an array

Comment: You don't need to copy it to an array to reverse it. You can do to a `std::string` the same thing as you would do to the array.

Comment: Why without a built-in function? There's no reason to "just practice" something like this, because there will always be a built in function to do it, so learning to do it manually isn't useful, and you wind up just learning old habits like using char arrays and manually reserving memory. `strlen` is a built-in function so why is it okay to use that, but not a function to reverse the string?

Comment: do you mean `std::string` and `char[]` ? If so, please fix your code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can copy a `std::string`'s contents into a `char` array (as shown in some other answers), *but you don't need to*.

The `std::string` contents can be used as an array! Use the `[]` operator on it.

Here we go:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string str = "Superb!";

   // Iterate over the first half of the string
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size() / 2; i++)
   {
      // What's the equivalent index at the other end?
      const std::size_t other_i = str.size() - i - 1;

      // Swap the values
      const char temp = str[i];
      str[i] = str[other_i];
      str[other_i] = temp;
   }

   // Have a look
   std::cout << str << '\n';   // Output: !brepuS
}
```

Easy!

This can be improved further in a few ways that you're not interested in:

- `std::string::size_type` is the "proper" way to spell `std::string` indexes;
- `std::swap` is preferred to the `char temp` gubbins;
- Writing out the loop by hand, other than for education reasons, is a bit silly;
- If you don't need in-place reversal a simple construction `std::string str2{str1.rbegin(), str2.rend()};` gets the job done;
- If you do, `std::reverse` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

> lets say I have a string I want to revese it without using built in
>   function

You do not need a char array. Just do whatever you were planning to do with the array with the string instead:

```
void reverse(std::string& s) {
     for (int i=0;i < s.size() / 2 ; ++i) {
         char temp = s[i];
         s[i] = s[ s.size() - i - 1];
         s[ size() - i - 1] = temp;
     }
}
```

(not compiled or tested)

Comment: "There arent any built in functions to reverse a string as far as I know." How about `std::reverse_copy()`?

Comment: And that is nitpicking :/

Comment: If you really want nitpicking, that is not a "method", because C++ doesn't have "methods" and even if it did they mean member functions, which `std::reverse_copy()` is not. And standard library functions are the built-in functions; no "built-in functions" in any other sense exist. The core language has operators and keywords though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you for being more nitpicky than me ;) well and for correcting me

Comment: @Swordfish after all you were right and I was wrong :)

Comment: @user463035818 My nitpickiness is dependable

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit actually I am not fully convinced to call `std::reverse_copy()` "built-in", however, as there are no built-in functions in any other sense, that distinctions is rather meaningless anyhow

Comment: @user463035818 Agreed, and that's fair

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say I have a string I want to revese it without using built in function. Is it possible to copy string into array directly?

I assume, that your `String` is `std::string`, `strlen(str)` is `str.length()` and `Char` is `char`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>  // std::unique_ptr<>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello, World!";
    auto len = str.length();
    auto strarray = std::make_unique<char[]>(len + 1);

    auto *a = strarray.get() + len - 1;
    auto *p = str.data();

    while (*p)
        *a-- = *p++;

    std::cout << strarray << '\n';
}
```

#### Output:

```
!dlroW ,olleH
```

Comment: I'm confused. You go out of your way to assume VLAs are permitted but then go out of your way not to use them...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Permitted in the OPs code, not in standard C++. .. but i changed the code a little.

Comment: Same confusion either way

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Removed the confusion alltogether.

Comment: That's better now ta

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I feel relieved ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this code to copy single-byte string into array. Don't forget about the null terminator to output the copied string.

```
std::string str = "Abc";
char* strarray = new char[str.length() + 1];
str.copy(strarray, str.length());
strarray[str.length()] = 0;
std::cout << strarray << std::endl;
delete[] strarray;
```